# Make 2x2 grid based on screen width

Tags: swiftui

Sorry if this is a simple question but I'm just starting out with SwiftUI and I'm trying to figure out how to make a 2x2 grid of views based on the width of the screen.  Meaning that each square has a width and height of have the screen width and they are arranged in a 2x2 grid with no padding.

I've been trying with two HStacks with two views in each placed on top of each other but the view size inside the HStack seems to dictate the HStack's height.

Code for Views I'm trying to arrange into the 2x2 grid:

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("0", text: $value)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
                .border(Color.black)
                .padding()

            Text(title)
                .padding([.leading, .bottom, .trailing])
                .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .regular, design: .rounded))
            }
                .background(Color.green)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 5))
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I find that using A combination of `HStack`s, `VStack`s and `aspectRatio(_ aspectRatio: CGFloat? = nil, contentMode: ContentMode)` works best for forcing certain proportions on views:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Rectangle().fill(Color.red)
                    .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
                Rectangle().fill(Color.green)
                    .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fill)
            }
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                Rectangle().fill(Color.blue)
                    .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fit)
                Rectangle().fill(Color.yellow)
                    .aspectRatio(1.0, contentMode: .fill)
            }
        }.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    }
}
```

Results in a layout like this:

[image: 2x2 grid]

Comment: Very nice and simple, without the use of a [`GeometryReader`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58462739/1971013). A `GeometryReader` can be handy for more complicated layouts.

Comment: That works with the Rectangles but the views I'm using have a Text and a TextField in them and when I use your above code the size of the squares is dictated by height of the Text + TextField, so you end up with 4 equally sized squares in the middle of the screen instead of the 4 large ones that are screenWidth / 2

Comment: You mention 2x2 grid, but your code includes only a Text and a TextField. Please let me know if they are meant to be within the same square or two separate ones and I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a `GeometryReader`:

```
struct ContentView: View
{
    var body: some View
    {
        GeometryReader
        { geometry in
            self.useProxy(geometry)
        }
    }

    func useProxy(_ geometry: GeometryProxy) -> some View
    {
        let dimension = min(geometry.size.width, geometry.size.height)
        return VStack
        {
            HStack(spacing: 0)
            {
                Text("Top Left")
                    .frame(width: dimension / 2, height: dimension / 2)
                    .border(Color.black)

               Text("Top Right")
                   .frame(width: dimension / 2, height: dimension / 2)
                   .border(Color.black)
            }

            HStack(spacing: 0)
            {
                Text("Bottom Left")
                    .frame(width: dimension / 2, height: dimension / 2)
                    .border(Color.black)

               Text("Bottom Right")
                   .frame(width: dimension / 2, height: dimension / 2)
                   .border(Color.black)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Watch (the first part of) [this WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/237) to hear about the layout system of SwiftUI.